# Sum all values in every column of a data.frame in R

Tags: r

Given this data set:

```
  Name Height Weight
1 Mary     65    110
2 John     70    200
3 Jane     64    115
```

I'd like to sum every qualifier columns (Height and Weight) yielding

```
 199  425
```

The problem is that the qualifiers can be more than just 2 (i.e. more
than just Height and Weight).

I can do this.

```
    # Create the dataframe people
    Name <- c("Mary", "John", "Jane")
    Height <- c(65,70,64)
    Weight <- c(110,200,115)
    people <- data.frame(Name, Height, Weight)

    res <- c(sum(people$Height),sum(people$Weight))
```

But it gets too long when the qualifier increase.
What's the compact way to do it?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use function `colSums()` to calculate sum of all values.  `[,-1]` ensures that first column with names of people is excluded.

```
 colSums(people[,-1])
Height Weight 
   199    425
```

Assuming there could be multiple columns that are not numeric, or that your column order is not fixed, a more general approach would be:

```
colSums(Filter(is.numeric, people))
```

Answer (score 23):

We can use `dplyr` to select only numeric columns and `purr` to get `sum` for all columns. (can be used to get what ever value for all columns, such as mean, min, max, etc. )

```
library("dplyr")
library("purrr")

people %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    map_dbl(sum)
```

Or another easy way by only using `dplyr` - As of (dplyr 1.0.0) we can use `across()`

```
library("dplyr")
people %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

```
library("dplyr")
people %>%
    summarize_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mapply(sum,people[,-1])

Height Weight 
   199    425
```

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completion:

```
 apply(people[,-1], 2, function(x) sum(x))
#Height Weight 
#   199    425
```

Comment: Yes, this does work, but it is strictly worse than `colSums` - less efficient, longer to type.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try `a <- apply(mtcars[,c(select.colums)], 2, sum )`

```
a <- apply(people[,c(2,3)], 2, sum )
```